# How to get a selection part in a crawler result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm crawling the page and how can I get only the src part in the console.
`[<iframe frameborder="0" id="svc-iframe" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="svc-iframe" src="https://google.com/p/productDeviceMatching/EXTERNAL_UK?amam2.serviceInfo=d9-LBKUSFNSLONZ2kGN6C9gPPnBDZ0_DtVqQbQ-ySbZQVwqyOvfb8lGmz0ZJileUgmfMCQANyfsgSGrUWlgk0JFlhXR-Gf2u3KT2S0vK4dRQTOKLXzVqITltBhMKeOWnuEU5ASC9X6jESpC3BwT5HaCnvOf4msgyQpA6NDl9L3OSPsuxIr0RgsJm-xMiPzz03dvrGsstUboRlK_IdAZuQwmc1599LPsFxDdYlaBS3SZbLUJpoJ6uNypr_BcJV_VtAaKmF_taYVfbN_XCKoOmDLQmDNdWsJEhkwEocra8ZaofUBlSaYtNRL8ABoW2mV5mo-MHphRJHtZEi38uSqgK4qdVxIJ9yedU8XwWOiMfy0Y0x1nS5SOh5w"></iframe>]`

For example, I want only the below parts
`https://google.com/p/productDeviceMatching/EXTERNAL_UK?amam2.serviceInfo=d9-LBKUSFNSLONZ2kGN6C9gPPnBDZ0_DtVqQbQ-ySbZQVwqyOvfb8lGmz0ZJileUgmfMCQANyfsgSGrUWlgk0JFlhXR-Gf2u3KT2S0vK4dRQTOKLXzVqITltBhMKeOWnuEU5ASC9X6jESpC3BwT5HaCnvOf4msgyQpA6NDl9L3OSPsuxIr0RgsJm-xMiPzz03dvrGsstUboRlK_IdAZuQwmc1599LPsFxDdYlaBS3SZbLUJpoJ6uNypr_BcJV_VtAaKmF_taYVfbN_XCKoOmDLQmDNdWsJEhkwEocra8ZaofUBlSaYtNRL8ABoW2mV5mo-MHphRJHtZEi38uSqgK4qdVxIJ9yedU8XwWOiMfy0Y0x1nS5SOh5w"></iframe>]`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `xpath` in your crawl you can search with this expression

`//iframe[@id='svc-iframe']/@src`